# UK Visitor Visa and 2x Tier 5 refusals

Tags: visa-refusals

Sorry this is a long one.

I have previously studied and lived in the UK for 5 years. I returned to SA after my studies where I have been living and working since my return from UK.

However, in 2015 I decided to apply for a visitor visa to visit old friends....After the death of my mum, I needed a break.
Here's where it all goes pear shaped.

Immigration refuse my Visitor visa on the following grounds:

1. I did not prove to them that I did not overstay previously (but they told me that Home office said I left UK in 2005...which DID)
   *I misplaced the passport I left the UK with and never thought of keeping the plane ticket either. As these documents would prove I never overstayed. Surely the airports could confirm my return to SA. Immigration say they have no record of my return to SA. (how about an interview)?*
2. They said I made an application at the Home office UK in 2012,
   *which is definitely untrue, and I proved this by way of payslip and letter from my current employer here in SA and also suggested they check my cctv at work.*
3. I do not have any family commitments to return to SA
   *Well, nowhere on that application form does it ask about what responsibilities you have to return to etc.
   In my admin review I gave a list of responsibilities I had to come back to at the time. Firstly I had a permanent job, I had just lost my mum and I have the house to look after. I was also taking care of my niece who suffers with schizophrenia Dr letters were submitted with that application.*

I was so disheartened, I did not think to apply for an administrative review

Anyway, a year later, I get an offer to do support work in the UK,  I apply for a Tier 5 visa with my friend as we were both offered the job. We BOTH did not submit evidence that we have previously done support work. Her visa is issued to her and mine is refused because of the following.:

1. I did not raise the issues of the 1st refusal.
2. I did not submit proof that I can do the job.
3. And I still have not prove that I did not overstay.

I did not raise the issues as I assumed this was a different category and nowhere on the application did it ask for this information.
I do have a certificate from a Disability course I did through grass roots UK, however I did not submit this at the time, my fault. But my question is, why was friend not asked for this proof?

I then apply for an admin review, and showed the certificate, an affidavit stating that the passport was lost.

The review upheld the refusal because I was not allowed to submit that evidence to the review, but suggested I reapply, which I'd did. Only to be refused again. What a waste of money.
The reasons for refusal.

1. The signatures on the certificate are not original.
2. I did not submit a description of the job I'm going to do.
3. I am not currently actively doing support work in my country.

I contacted Grass roots uk who have confirmed the signatories authorised to sign certificates did in fact sign my certificate.

A job description was submitted with my application but removed and handed back to me by a staff member at the visa office. I did not question that as I assumed she knew what she was doing.

I have done support work hence my certificate, and my current situation does not allow me to do support work on a permanent basis. Although I do care for an 88yr old lady in my area, and this is done voluntary.

My question is where did immigration get their information from and was a graphology St used for the signatures.

Comment: It would be better if you can post the refusal letters here after blacking out the personal details for you to receive a proper answer. The previous refusal would have made them look into your case with extra diligence and any shortcomings in the application would make for an immediate refusal.

Comment: Please scan and redact and post the images of your refusal notices. Your question is too complex otherwise.  See http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/how-do-i-upload-an-image/4090#4090 for more info and help...

Comment: There is little point in comparing the handling of your visa to your friend's. You probably have different travel and visa application histories, which can affect the degree of scrutiny a new application gets. I suggest shortening the question by deleting that aspect.

Comment: It may help you if you treat this not as an opportunity to engage in vexatious legalistic disputes with officials but instead try to work out what they expect and want to see. Asking them to check work CCTV for evidence of your attendance suggests you are not fully conscious that (fairly or not) the onus is on **you** to provide credible, accurate, comprehensive but succinct proof of eligibility for a visa. Such proof *must* be in the form specified in the published guidance.

Comment: hanks everyone....@DumbCoder...I think i will post the refusal letters so you have a better understanding. @Redgrittybrick Please note, I did submit proof that I was in SA at the time in the form of payslip and letter from employer and since that was not sufficient I only suggested they check cctv at my job to help my case. Thanks for the advice as I am feeling victimised.@Patricia Shanahan I do understand that every case is dealt with differently,  I am just trying to understand how is it fair that she was not asked for that documentation and I was. She has no previous experience either